# Call timer function for several times in ajax success event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my current code for timer:

```
function startTimer() {
    var duration = 60*3;
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        $('.minutes').html(minutes);
        $('.seconds').html(seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

This function is working, let say I got an ajax to call this function :

```
 $.ajax({
        url : '/sample_url/',
        success : function (data) 
        {
           startTimer();
        }
});
```

Here is my question, I run this `startTimer` function is ok, however if I used ajax to call it for several times, the timer not countdown at 3 minutes...

Comment: When exactly you want to make another ajax call ?

Comment: I need to call other countdown on the same page without page reload...since I need to execute several events and can countdown correctly...

Comment: Put entire code of yours so that one can examine the scenario...

Comment: All required codes for timer only that...

Comment: startTimer is working as expected..Just need to check when you are calling this function..must be missing something there...